# Copying data from parent model instance when child model instance is saved

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a parent model which contains a database of unique records, as follows (truncated - there are many more fields):

**models.py - parent**

```
class DBPlatform(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    PDS_date = models.DateField()
    PDS_version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I use this model to create a child model to save me copying all of the fields. The child model saves specific user-generated instances of the parent records. They are stored separately as they may be edited by the user:

**models.py - child**

```
class Platform(DBPlatform):

    scenario = models.ForeignKey(Scenario,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="platforms")
    database_platform = models.ForeignKey(DBPlatform,
                                          on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                          related_name="instances")
    edited = models.BooleanField()
```

I am using Django REST Framework to create an API for the eventual app. When a child model is created, I want to update all of its inherited fields with those of the parent model. The incredibly convoluted steps I have taken so far (that do not work) are in the views.py file of the child mode. As follows:

**api.views.py - child**

```
class PlatformViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = "id"
    serializer_class = PlatformSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        db_id = self.request.data["database_platform"]
        database_platform = get_object_or_404(DBPlatform, id=db_id)

        datadict = self.request.data.dict()
        datadict.update(database_platform.__dict__)

        query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        query_dict.update(datadict)

        self.request.data = query_dict

        serializer.save()
```

How can I achieve what I am looking to do? I surely am taking the wrong approach as this can't be an uncommon thing.

**EDIT**:
Ruddra's comment has made me consider that the whole design pattern is faulty. Should I just be using a single model and a boolean flag for the "template" instance?

Comment: I don't get it, why you need to copy data from parent to child? Why you need to keep duplicate data?

Comment: The parent instances are templates, that may be edited by the user in the child instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serializer` data is not changed by the operations before `serializer.save()`.
If you want to do it this way, you'll have edit the `serializer` or re-serialize the data.

Unless this is something that needs to happen only through API and only on this endpoint, I'd suggest overwriting the model's `save` method or using `pre_save` signal. To make sure this operation is performed only when creating a new instance, you can check if `self` (in case of overwriting `save`) or `instance` (in case of signal) has `id`.

Comment: So this solution worked and quite neatly in signals.py but unfortunately of course duplicated the parent class when a new child class was created, which is what I did not want. But was the solution to the question asked.